# Determining Mutual Exclusion in Evaluating Integer Rules

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I am trying to solve a problem regarding creation of Rule Engine. 
Let's say i have an input x and following set of Rules:

1. x> 100 && x<200
2. x < 500 && x > 200

Now, I have to create a new Rule into the system and need to check if the new rule is mutually exclusive or not. For instance :

1. x < 1000 # Not Mutually Exclusive as it will trigger both the rules.
2. x < 1000 && x > 400 # Not Mutually Exclusive as it will trigger one of the rules.
3. x > 1000 # Mutually Exclusive.

**Problem is that, based on input you check the uniqueness which most Rule Engines do but need any leads or directions on how to create a rule and determine that for variable inputs, the newly created Rule will be Mutually Exclusive to the previously created rules.**

Comment: I'd think you run it by all the rules and see if it is exclusive for each one. If one of them is not exclusive, you've got the answer. If none of them do, then that is the answer

Comment: but the x value can be anything, and set can be too large and too many comparison.
Need to optimise on this approach.
You have to find all the possible values of x from both rules and then execute the third one. Is there any better and. leaner way?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using strategy pattern . Each rule will have its own strategy i.e. implementation . Depending upon the result ,you can chose weather to continue or exit .

Comment: You can use Rule Engines for that. The real question here is to determine if the rule will be mutually exclusive for any set of values. The thing to achieve here is for no such inputs should 2 rules execute simultaneously.

Comment: @jatinmahajan , please let us know if your problem is solved with  https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rangeset

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Guava RangeSet can help you. And there especially the method 'RangeSet#intersects' which returns a boolean value if a range intersects with another range.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import com.google.common.collect.RangeSet;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet;

public class RangeSetTest {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        RangeSet<Integer> numberRangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();

        numberRangeSet.add(Range.closed(101, 199));  // x> 100 && x<200
        numberRangeSet.add(Range.closed(201, 499));  // x < 500 && x > 200

        System.out.println(numberRangeSet.intersects(Range.lessThan(1000)));     // x < 1000
        System.out.println(numberRangeSet.intersects(Range.closed(401, 999)));  // x < 1000 && x > 400
        System.out.println(numberRangeSet.intersects(Range.greaterThan(1000)));  // x > 1000
    }  
}
```

mvn dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting started guide to [Guava RangeSet from baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rangeset)

Comment: Seems like a solution, let me explore the solution once and will share my findings.